# Hack into sys_open in kernel and grab file content to a buffer

Tags: kernel, system-calls

I am trying to hack into the system call "sys_open" in fs/open.c and grab the content of file into a char* buffer.  Here is the call stack:
sys_open -> filp_open -> dentry_open, and I added the following codes at the end of dentry_open in order to read the file content to buffer but did not work, any ideas?

```
char *buf = kmalloc(sizeof(*f), GFP_KERNEL);
mm_segment_t fs;
fs = get_fs();
set_fs(get_ds());
f->f_op->read(f, buf, sizeof(*f), 0);
set_fs(fs);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I addressed the problem by self.

By directly calling "kernel_read()"